# Can we initialize WebDriverWait inside class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

Can we use initialize [WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10);] WebDriverWait inside a class?

Suppose within a class I have 10 methods, so instead of initializing the wait 10 times in each method I was thinking to initialize once outside of all methods and within the class.

I have a framework where i read data from an excel sheet and run the test methods. Now when i initialize the wait outside the method i am observing that the data is not being read from excel and the browser closes.

It has nothing to do with data reader. Some issue with initializing the wait outside the method.

Same case i tried to initialize the wait inside those 10 methods it words fine.

Any reason for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize it directly as an instance variable, unless you have some `WebDriverFactory` which allows you to pass the `driver` to `new WebDriverWait()` before object is initialized. You can, however, try to initialize it in the constructor like this:

```
public class PageObject {
    private WebDriverWait wait;

    public PageObject(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    }
}
```

and then use `wait` in your methods.

Comment: Yes, suppose we have already a driver instance initialized in the constructor , then can we initialize the wait outside the constructor (within the class but outside of any methods). I tried to do that,eclipse didnt gave any warning or error , but data was not being read because of initializing it in that way . Need to know it why.

Comment: @shikhar I need to see the code of how do you do it

Comment: What i was trying was is in link - https://controlc.com/a8c19e01

Although when i tried to initialize the WebDriverWait within the constructor it worked as expected.

The code which i wrote executed without warning or error but the execution paused after a period of time. If i remove the initialization of webdriver wait outside the method and initialize it within the method it works.

Dont know why initializing outside doesnt work. :(

Comment: @shikhar Becase you pass `null` WebDriver to `WebDriverWait` and THEN assign the value to `driver` variable.

Comment: @Fenio- Thankyou i understand your point, I am pasting a code snippet i am using kind of same format. Will WebDriverWait still be null in the code snippet . Code available at -https://pastebin.com/8matgCNp . Will be great if you can help me in understanding how webdriverwait is null in the code snippet, and any way we can check if its null or not.

Comment: @shikhar Yes, it will still be null. Instance variables are initialized first. They are meant to be initialized before constructor OR initialized in constructor.

Comment: Thankyou so much for making me understand it .